# What does genetic diversity in one species have to do with survival rate when an epidemic spreads?

Tags: genetics, immunology, ecology, biodiversity, fitness

I was studying about genes, and soon remembered that the more diverse the genetics of one species, the less the chance of the species to go extinct from natural disaster.

One instance was an epidemic spreads.
I don't fully understand why that happens, so I searched for it in Google and books, but all of them only told me that it is true, not why or how.

So my question is : **why and how genetic diversity in one species affects the chance of the species's extinction**?
I mean, for example, does it relate to antibodies or something else?

Comment: you might need to change some key words when you search the net for information i found this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_diversity and this https://www.biologyonline.com/dictionary/genetic-diversity by searching for "what is genetic diversity"

Comment: If everyone has the same weakness, then one thing targeting that weakness can wipe everyone out. If everyone has different weaknesses, then that is no longer the case.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. If you are wondering about the downvotes it is probably because the Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers (Google is a tool), what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: I would recommend looking at the "Evolutionary diversity" section of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_histocompatibility_complex). (for vertebrates, at least)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Genetic diversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_diversity) could be understood as a variation in [alleles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allele) (gene variants) and their [frequencies](https://www.nature.com/scitable/definition/allele-frequency-298) in a population. Due to these allelic variations, we would expect an inherent variability in individual [genotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genotype) (or genetic codes). [Phenotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenotype) (or traits) can and do vary with changes in underlying genotype. (In simple terms: if you change the underlying genetic code, it could result in changes to an individual's traits).

Changes in traits (e.g., color, size, speed, temperature regulation, mobility, etc.) could lead to a variation in energy conservation, survival, reproductive success, and ultimately [fitness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_(biology)).

If any member of a population is more *fit* given a set of environmental circumstances, it is morel likely that they will survive and pass on their genes to subsequent generations.

- You would benefit from reviewing [evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microevolution) and [natural selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection). ([Sexual selection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexual_selection) and [genetic drift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_drift) are relevant, too, of course).

However, the environment and resulting ecologies are always *changing*, and so there is never an "endpoint" of this process. I.e., there's never a *perfectly* fit individual that will survive all future environmental changes better than all other variants. In fact, all organisms can only tolerate [stressful](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/pdf/S0960-9822(14)00488-6.pdf) environmental conditions to a point. (See, e.g., [principle of allocation](https://bio.libretexts.org/Courses/University_of_California_Davis/BIS_2B%3A_Introduction_to_Biology_-_Ecology_and_Evolution/)).

- As a result, any given individual is limited in its ability to survive various environmental conditions, and *no* individual organism can survive *all* possible environmental conditions.

**With genetic diversity (and therefore the resulting variability in *traits*), a given population has members that may be better suited to survive a broad[er] range of environmental situations/changes/outcomes.**

Therefore, it's less of an issue of survival *rate* and instead sustainability of the genetics of that population and life in general.

- If a population lacks genetic diversity, then there is a greater chance that the population as a whole goes extinct.

Example:

*Population of rabbits that have variability in their alleles dictating fur length. If there was no variability in their genes (the extreme case being that they're all clones), then any massive shift in climatic conditions (e.g., temperature) may decrease their entire population to 0. If, however, we have some rabbits with alleles that could now or in later combinations result in longer fur, that would enable some members to survive very cold years. This population would be in trouble if it suddenly turned very warm. But if our population's initial gene pool also contained alleles that could now or later result in a short fur phenotype, then the population is even *better* protected from extinction in these various scenarios.*

I think you could figure out how this applies to pathogens in the context of an epidemic...

- Hint: traits could also include metabolic rates, biochemical processes, cell-surface proteins, etc.)

---

<sup>This could get much more complicated, but this gives you the introductory understanding I think you're looking for.</sup>